# Need examples of how to use Repository OrderBy

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, repository

Entity Framework has an associated Repository that provides built in functions for standard operations. One of these functions is a generalized Get(filter, orderby, includeList) method. I know how to use the filter and includeList, but I've not figured out how to use the orderby parameter. The orderby parameter is given as:

```
Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null
```

and the evaluation is:

```
     IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbSet;

     if (orderBy != null) {
        return orderBy(query).ToList();
     } else {
        return query.ToList();
     }
```

Any hints or examples will get me started
Thanks.

Comment: What is this "associated Repository"? Do you have this from some third-party library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like so:

```
Func<IQueryable<SomeEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<SomeEntity>> orderBy
    = q => q.OrderBy(e => e.SomePropertyOfSomeEntity);
```

Comment: Thanks, that shines a light on the issue.

Comment: @Slauma i need to create this orderby expression dynamically. do you know any idea how can i do that?

Comment: @bahadirarslan: If you mean that you only have the fields to order by as strings then *Dynamic Linq* is on option: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: Actually you are right but i had implemented Repository pattern as told here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx So i need to create that expression to call Get method.